# Database migration from magento 1.9.3.6 to magento 2.4.4-p2

Tags: magento2.4, migration, data-migration-tool, monolog

For migrate Database I installed migration tool using composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.4.4. After composer install run bib/magento setup:upgrade command. But it raises an error like

Warning: Declaration of Migration\Logger\Logger::addRecord(int $level, stri
ng $message, array $context = Array): bool should be compatible with Monolo
g\Logger::addRecord(int $level, string $message, array $context = Array, ?M
onolog\DateTimeImmutable $datetime = NULL): bool in /var/www/html/m244p2.lo
cal/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Logger/Logger.php on l
ine 34

Note magento version - 2.4.4-p2
monolog version - 2.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Your error indicates that incompatible between `Migration\Logger\Logger::addRecord` and `Monolo g\Logger::addRecord` method dueto Monolog\Logger just change their method param.

To fix this error, edit file `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Logger/Logger.php`
and change `addRecord` method to:

```
public function addRecord(int $level, string $message, array $context = Array, ?M
onolog\DateTimeImmutable $datetime = NULL): bool
```

Comment: If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as **accepted**, it makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.

Comment: yes. Issue was fixed for me. I changes addRecord method to
public function addRecord(int $level, string $message, array $context = [], \Monolog\DateTimeImmutable $datetime = null): bool

Comment: Glad to hear that, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.